# Ubuntu 12.04 and Mono CompilationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mono

I just intstalled my new vServer running on Ubunt 12.04
I set up Mono like described here : http://datachomp.com/archives/running-asp-net-mvc4-on-ubuntu-12-04/

But everything I do I get this Exception:

> System.Web.Compilation.CompilationException :   at
>   IKVM.Reflection.Reader.ModuleReader.ResolveType (Int32 metadataToken,
>   IGenericContext context) [0x00000] in :0
>
> Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this
>   request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.
>   Details: : at IKVM.Reflection.Reader.ModuleReader.ResolveType (Int32
>   metadataToken, IGenericContext context) [0x00000] in :0 Error origin: Compiler Error source file: ~/Global.asax
>   Exception stack trace:   at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly
>   (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath,
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly
>   (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in :0
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly
>   (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder,
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group,
>   System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner
>   (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in :0

Anyone knows the answer to my problem ?

Thanks a lot